# Is the mass of Kuiper belt dominated by large objects?

Tags: solar-system, kuiper-belt

There is a problem in my example sheet trying to teach me distributions. My result is that Kuiper belt objects are dominated by large mass objects. Is this supported by observational evidence?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you call large. There may be hundreds of thousands of icy bodies larger than 100 km (62 miles) and an estimated trillion or more comets within the Kuiper Belt. But the total mass of objects in the Kuiper belt is estimated to be less than 10% of earth's mass.  So the Kuiper belt is largly composed of small icy onjects. These objects are very hard to see with existing telescopes because the are so small and not much sunlight where they are.

References:
https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/solar-system/kuiper-belt/in-depth/

https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/792/10-things-to-know-about-the-kuiper-belt/

https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/solar-system/kuiper-belt/overview/